# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Please find the [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRVC5.jpg) here.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.TStamp).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}").Filterable(f => f.Enabled(false));
columns.Bound(p => p.EventType).Filterable(f => f.Enabled(false));
columns.Bound(p => p.App.AppNameFull).Title("App Name"); //.Filterable(f => f.UI("appsFilter"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you are using Grid.MVC. I checked out [this](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Filtering) page. You should pass only bool inside the `.Filterable(true)` method.

Comment: Thanks it worked but now im getting An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code Error

Comment: public ActionResult AppsDropdownRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IEnumerable<App> dataSource = this.appService.GetApps(string.Empty);

            return this.Json(dataSource.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } in return im gettring the exeption

Comment: sorry this is not directly related to the question(and I have no expertise in EntityFramework), so I would suggest you to raise it in a new question thread after you do the initial research. Please accept the answer if helpful, it helps future users too.